# unordered list not visible when I test code in browser

Tags: html, css

The following html code is leaving the whole unordered list invisible when I try to view it in browser from within eclipse.  I would like it to be simple html that works on any browser.  How do I change the below so that the unordered list becomes visible?  (Note: I edited the posting to include the full code.)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

<head> 
    <title>page title</title> 
    <meta name="description" content="meta text.">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head> 

<body> 
    <table width="95%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" style="padding: 10; margin: 10; border-collapse: collapse"> 
        <tr style="padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color:#336699">
            <td width="15%" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: large; background-color:#336699; border: 2px solid #FFCC66;">
                <a href="page1.html" class="toc">one</a><br/> 
              </td> 
            <td width="17%" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: large; background-color:#336699; border: 2px solid #FFCC66;">
                  <a href="page2.html" class="toc">two</a><br>
            </td> 
            <td width="17%" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: large; background-color:#336699; border: 2px solid #FFCC66;">
                  <a href="page3.html" class="toc">three</a><br>
            </td>
            <td width="17%" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: large; background-color:#336699; border: 2px solid #FFCC66;">
                  <a href="page4.html" class="toc">four</a><br>
            </td> 
            <td width="17%" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: large; background-color:#336699; border: 2px solid #FFCC66;">
                  <a href="page5.html" class="toc">five</a><br>
            </td> 
            <td width="17%" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: large; background-color:#336699; border: 2px solid #FFCC66;">
                <a href="page6.html" class="toc">six</a><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="6">
                <h1>the title</h1>
                    <p><img src="images/animage.gif" align="right">three items follow:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><b>topic1:</b> description1.</li>
                        <li><b>topic2:</b> description2.</li>
                        <li><b>topic3:</b> description3.</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>some text</p>
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td align=center colspan="5">
                <p>some text.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5">
                <p>some text.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Also, just for kicks, the css file contains the following:

```
h1 {color:#003366; font-size:150%; text-align:center}
h3 {color:#003366}
html {color:white}
p {margin-left:20px; color:#003366; font-size: large}
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color:white;}
a.toc:link {color:#FFCC66;}      /* unvisited link */
a.toc:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a.toc:hover {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* mouse over link */
a.toc:active {color:#336699;}  /* selected link */
a.body:link {color:#993300;}      /* unvisited link */
a.body:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a.body:hover {color:#097054;}  /* mouse over link */
a.body:active {color:#336699;}  /* selected link */
```

Comment: The list looks fine. What's up with your table though? Do you have `<table>` tags outside this?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, there are table tags. What else can you suggest?

Comment: Is this all the code you have? Something above it might be breaking, thus the page stops rendering.

Comment: There is nothing in this code to indicate why the `ul` should not be visible. Consider showing the whole code or a JSFiddle

Comment: @Pekka웃 I just edited the posting to include the entire code for the page.  Now is the problem visible?

Comment: @RUJordan I just edited the posting to include the entire code for the page.  Now is the problem visible?

Comment: Did I just see a `<b>` in there?

Comment: Is there something in mycss.css controlling unordered lists or their children elements?

Comment: @SetSailMedia I just added the css file contents.  Can you see any way to fix the problem now?

Comment: @Terry Yes, there are <b> tags.  Is this a problem?

Comment: Is the list not visible in all browsers or just the eclipse browser? Try testing it in other browsers. Also try using chrome dev tools or firebug to inspect the markup. This may allow you to find out if some sort of CSS rule is the cause or if it is just not rendering at all.

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo It is not visible in internet explorer, and also not visible in the eclipse browser. I want code so simple that it will work in every browser.  I do not want fancy code that has to be browser specific.

Comment: @kalley's answer looks good below - thanks for posting the CSS!@

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You problem is a combination of these rules:

```css
html {color:white}
```

and

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color:white;}
```

the `color` rule is setting all the font to be `white`. White on white tends to be hard to see.

And for the font, based on what you have above.

```css
p { margin-left:20px }
p, ul { color:#003366; font-size: large }
```

Comment: +1 and credit for the answer.  Thank you.  But can you please complete the answer by showing how to use the same font in the ul as in the p tags?  When I change to html{color:#003366}, the text shows up in the right color, but in the wrong font.

Comment: @CodeMed if you want the ul to have the same font, you could do `p { margin-left:20px } p, ul { color:#003366; font-size: large }`

Comment: Do you mind writing the exact lines of code for your css suggestions in your answer?  The things I am adding into my css file based on your suggestions are not fixing the problem of different fonts in the ul tag and the p tags. Maybe I am not understanding your suggestion?

Comment: Is your question about the actual font-family? You don't have any definitions for font families in your css. I've moved what I wrote into my answer, though it sounds like you need to read up on some basic CSS information. [This might be a good place to start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css)